# Add object properties in retrospect using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, updates

I'm creating a program that is reading in data from different text files and saves the information to objects. I have no problem creating an object from the information of one text file.

Imagine for example if I create a class that looks like the following:

```
class Stock:
    def __init__(self, company_name, solidity, share_price, p_e, p_s, beta_value, max_value, min_value):
        self.company_name = company_name
        self.solidity = solidity
        self.share_price = share_price
        self.p_e = p_e
        self.p_s = p_s
        self.beta_value = beta_value
        self.max_value = max_value
        self.min_value = min_value
```

And I create an object with only half of the attributes like this:

```
stock = Stock(company_name, 0, share_price, 0, 0, beta_value, 0, 0)
```

How do I later on add further information to the same object, even if I have many objects, for example:

```
stock = Stock(0, solidity, 0, p_e, p_s, 0, max_value, min_value)
```

Comment: Renamed `Aktie` to `Stock`. Stick to one language (english).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the values you want like this

```
stock.solidity = solidity
stock.p_e = p_e
stock.p_s = p_s
stock.max_value = max_value
stock.min_value = min_value
```

Comment: Ok, so lets say i have many objects saved in a list called "stocks". How do i assign that to the first object for example? Does it do that automatically?

Comment: is `stocks[0].solidity = solidity` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to call `Stock(0, solidity, 0, p_e, p_s, 0, max_value, min_value)` after the first, this will create another instance of your class.

What you need is to implement a method in your class that allows to update the attributes given later.

Another tip, when you have many parameters, you should use named-parameters to make it easy. Also it allows to define default parameters and avoid to give all the parameters each time:

```
class Stock():
    def __init__(self, company_name='', solidity=0, 
                 share_price=0, p_e=0, p_s=0, 
                 beta_value=0, max_value=0, min_value=0):
        self.company_name = company_name
        self.solidity = solidity
        self.share_price = share_price
        self.p_e = p_e
        self.p_s = p_s
        self.beta_value = beta_value
        self.max_value = max_value
        self.min_value = min_value

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs:
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])

s = Stock(solidity=10,
          share_price=120
          )

s.update(beta_value=12)
```

Comment: Ok this looks very promising thank you! :) the thing is only that i want the code to work for an undefined amount of objects. so now the code reads data from a txt-file and saves them to objects in a list. So now i don't know how to update every object in this list with different information without manually assigning them variables like "s". Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: the variable `s` is just a poor example, it will work with any kind of reference to the objects, like `list_of_stocks[0].update(p_e=3)`, or with obejcts in a for loop : `for item in list_of_stocks: item.update(p_e=3)`